# Spring Hibernate MySQL - No connection?

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs, spring, hibernate

I've a problem with connection to mysql. This is my code:

Dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>      
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Database Connection Pool -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL JDBC Driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.30</version>       
    </dependency>  
</dependencies>
```

Context:

```
  <mvc:annotation-driven /> 
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.packt.app" />

<bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://ADMIN-PC:3306/data"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean> 

<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="testDAO" class="com.packt.app.DAO.Impl.TestDAOImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/tests")
public class TestController {

@Autowired
TestService testService;

@RequestMapping("/testslist.json")
public @ResponseBody List<Test> getTestList() {
    return testService.getTests();
}

@RequestMapping("/layout")
public String getTestPartialPage(ModelMap modelMap) {
    return "tests/layout";
}
}
```

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test") 
public class Test{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

///gettters and setters
}
```

Impl:

```
@Repository
public class TestDAOImpl implements TestDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public TestDAOImpl() {
}

public TestDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public List<Test> getTests() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Test> tests = (List<Test>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createCriteria(Test.class)
            .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
    return tests;
}
}
```

Angular Controller:

```
var TestsController = function($scope, $http) {
$scope.test = {};
$scope.editMode = false;

$scope.fetchTestList = function() {
    $http.get('tests/testslist.json').success(function(testList){
        $scope.tests = testList;
    });
};

$scope.resetTestForm = function() {
    $scope.resetError();
    $scope.test = {};
    $scope.editMode = false;
};

$scope.resetError = function() {
    $scope.error = false;
    $scope.errorMessage = '';
};

$scope.setError = function(message) {
    $scope.error = true;
    $scope.errorMessage = message;
};

$scope.fetchTestList()();

$scope.predicate = 'id';
};
```

Hibernate config:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>        
<session-factory>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property> 

<mapping class="com.packt.app.model.Test"/>   
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Application runs without error, even when MySql Server off. In html view show me that list count "getTests" is 0. It looks like application not connection with MySQL Server. Whats wrong? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The dialect in hibernate configuratiin is missing a L

Should be mysqlDialect i reckon.

Comment: No, isn't the point. It's ok, Sorry my mistake while copying here. I've corrected

Comment: Did you try to debug you application and see if the getTests() method is call?

Comment: Just a curiosity, since you are using annotation in your dao why are you also define the bean in the xml configuration?

Comment: when I delete in the xml nothing changes. I'm still learning so I don't know how is good "schema"